# Architecture for SignalR (WebSockets) connection in stateless scalable web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, signalr

I will make a stateless, scalable web application. This is second nature to me and not an issue.

However, this one will use SignalR and as such will establish a WebSocket connection to each user.

Imagine my web application is scaled up to 5 different web servers, handling the load from 5000 concurrent users. These users will establish a WebSocket connection, and even though a load balancer will make sure the load is distributed among the 5 web servers, each user will be connected to one specific web server.

Now comes the question. If an event occurs and I want to send this event to one of my connected users, how do I do this?

The user could be connected to any web server, so I imagine that either I need some database where I keep track of which users are connected to which web server? or I need to send all messages to all web servers, which will then pass the message on to the user if he is connected?

The latter doesn't seem scalable. The first seems to be what I have to do, unless someone here can tell me a best practice approach to managing this challenge.

Comment: Did you not find anything useful on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr)?

Comment: I did not look for this in the docs. I only expect the SignalR docs to tell how it works in itself, not how to use it in this scenario I am describing.

Comment: Well, the link I mentioned shows how to us it in your scenario. It describes the overall architecture using backplane. Have you even read it?

Comment: I apologize. I did not see it was a link, I thought you just asked if I had looked in the docs as a general inquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to introduce into your application what is called a backplane. A backplane is basically an extra layer of messaging in your application that integrates with SignalR and handles the distributed nature of your serverfarm.

Currently, there are a number of technologies you can use, I recommend you take a look at Redis, I have managed to use it in bigger projects with good performance characteristics:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis

Comment: Thank you. This "backplane" keyword seems very promising. However, I am not finding any resources related to this architecture in a software context. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: (regarding which tool to use to temporarily store information, it is not very important for this question, I am more interested in the architecture aspect of it currently)

Comment: See the link I provided in the comments. It describes the architecture

Comment: Whilst this is kind of the right answer (I up voted it), its worth pointing out that a backplane might struggle for 5000 users unless they really don't do much. i.e. Test it

Comment: Sorry for not going through the link properly, I focused on "backplane" instead, which was too broad. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: @thab do you have any other keywords to look for in case where more scalability is needed?

Comment: Take a look at the limitations section within https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr - but bear in mind you might be OK... I've seen a suggestion that if a backplane won't work - you can try wholely separate nodes (I.e. In a chat example - rooms starting with a-m on node 1 and n-z on node 2 etc) - that's added code but will definitely scale better than using a backplane